# Can I use pagination with the $wpdb class?

Tags: pagination, wordpress

Let's say I want to use the $wpdb class to retrieve image locations from the database so I can then create a gallery of images. I have this code, but when I press 'next', the link doesn't seem to go anywhere. Am I missing something?

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$offset = 0;
if( isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']) ){
$offset =  ($_GET['page']-1) * 10; // (page 2 - 1)*10 = offset of 10
}
$pics = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT pic_thumb_url FROM wp3_bp_album 
WHERE owner_type = 'user' ORDER BY title DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset"
);
//LIMIT shows 10 results per page
//OFFSET will 'skip' this number off results. On page 1 the offset is 0 on page 2 it is 10       (if 10 results per page)
foreach($pics as $pic) :
echo '<a href ="'. '#' .'" > <img src="' . $pic . '">' . '</a>';

endforeach; 


/*
pagination
*/
?>
<a href="/community/?page=<?php echo $_GET['page']-1 ?>">previous</a>
<a href="/community/?page=<?php echo $_GET['page']+1 ?>">next</a>
```

Can I implement pagination with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the built-in pagination, but to use pagination use an `OFFSET` and a `LIMIT` in your query. So, make your own pagination:

```
<?php
$offset = 0;
if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']) {
    $offset =  ($_GET['page']-1) * 10; // (page 2 - 1)*10 = offset of 10
}
$wpdb->get_col("SELECT pic_thumb_url FROM wp3_bp_album 
    WHERE owner_type = 'user' ORDER BY title DESC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset"
);
//LIMIT shows 10 results per page
//OFFSET will 'skip' this number off results. On page 1 the offset is 0 on page 2 it is 10 (if 10 results per page)

/*
pagination
*/
?>
<a href="/currentpage/?page=<?php echo $_GET['page']-1 ?>">previous</a>
<a href="/currentpage/?page=<?php echo $_GET['page']+1 ?>">next</a>
```

Not flawless, it doesn't check if you are on the first or last page but at least the first check you have to build yourself.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean. What do you mean by "You can't use the build in pagination", and could you give me an example of the OFFSET and limit? Thank you!

Comment: Wordpress has build in pagination functions like: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links it won't work with your code. SQL in edit

Comment: Thanks Janw. I used your reccomendation for offset and limit. I am now getting on 10 results on the page, but how do I actually paginate?

Comment: Make the offset a variable and fill that variable with a `$_GET` param. Make your own pagination at the bottom which sets that `$_GET`

Comment: Sorry I am not that good with PHP, could you be a little more specific or point me to a resource for working with $_get? All I know about it has something to do with the url query string.

Comment: Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp  You should make links like `<a href="yourdomain.com/image-page/?page=2">` then read that with php `echo $_GET['page];`($_GET in CAPS)

Comment: Ok I see, I will check that out. As far making my own pagination, can you clarify that as well? Sorry for all the questions, I'm new to this.

Comment: I don't mind helping but I'd appreciate it if you at least gave me an upvote. I'll update my answer with pagination.

Comment: Thanks for your work. I played around with the code you have written up, but there seems to be one problem. When I press 'next', nothing happens, it does not go to the next page. I will update my question with my current code.

Comment: try playing around by putting a `echo $offset` after it is set. Also look at your url's does there apear an `?page=x` behind it?